# How To Execute SSH Commands Via Symfony2 Process

Tags: php, symfony, ssh, process

I am trying to execute a script in a remote server and I am using the symfony process.

```
   $process = new Process('ssh -q root@remoteserver <path 2 script>');                                            
   $process->run();
```

When I execute this, I am getting NULL value.

Please note: The command I used is working fine in bash.

Comment: What do `$process->getOutput()` and `$process->getErrorOutput()` give you?

Comment: on which user you grant access via public/private key?

Comment: @qooplmao   
    ["stdout":"Symfony\Component\Process\Process":private]=> NULL 
    ["stderr":"Symfony\Component\Process\Process":private]=> NULL

Comment: @Matteo Grant access to root user via public/private key

Comment: remove the -q option (quiet) maybe that's why you don't have outputs